# Criar Serviço Windows Auto-Atualizável

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber o procedimento recomendado para que um serviço do Windows  possa se auto-atualizar.

As principais dúvidas são:

1. Após o serviço baixar uma nova versão dele mesmo, como parar o serviço e reiniciá-lo com a nova versão?
2. Que procedimentos adotar para que o mesmo não seja confundido com uma processo malicioso (assinar com `strong key` seria uma alternativa?)

Aceito também sugestões de bibliotecas (não paga) que realizem esta função.

Comment: No [CodePlex](https://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=auto%20update&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|&ac=2) cove encontra várias alternativa.

Comment: Pesquisei lá também, não encontrei nada que suprisse minha necessidade.

Comment: Com certeza vai ser difícil encontrar algo exato para teu caso, pois a tua abordagem tem especificações próprias. Mas a infraestrutura para você construir teu projeto existe.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow, existe a possibilidade de migrar essa aplicação para Web . Pois realizando esse procedimento basta alterar a DLL para que a aplicação seja atualizada. Geralmente não criamos aplicações Windows Services caso possuem a necessidade de muitas atualizações ou que a atualização seja inerente a vontade do usuário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há um meio simples de fazer um processo .Net se auto atualizar. Seria algo como cometer haraquiri e continuar vivendo para se auto reconstruir. O processo atualizador teria de estar executando em um Domain diferente e o Domain do processo a ser atualizado deve ser destruído.
Minha recomendação:
Use um processo auxiliar para efetuar o update.
1) O seu serviço detecta a necessidade de atualização, baixa o arquivo, inicia o processo auxiliar de update, encerra a execução de forma autônoma.
2) O processo auxiliar faz a atualização e reinicia o serviço, aguarda indicação de validação de execução e encerra.
Obs.: Voce deve aproveitar para fazer um backup da versão anterior, pois se não passar na validação do update a versão anterior poderá ser recolocada em operação.

Answer (score 3):

Já tentou utilizar o [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/t71a733d.aspx)?

Ele não tem suporte direto a instalação/atualização de serviços, porém existem alguns contornos que podem ser utilizados como está descrito [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25488153/929324) ou [aqui](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5cb2170e-34c0-4eb6-bd94-5fa1c9fb0387/deploy-windows-service-using-clickonce-deployment?forum=winformssetup).

Comment: É uma abordagem interessante mas não se encaixa no contexto do meu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer com que ele baixe o update para uma pasta temporária e no final da atualização um outro executável (pode até ser um arquivo .bat) mova os arquivos e reexecute o programa.

Answer (score 1):

Intercale o ClickOnce e/ou WebService para fazer isto para você

[Veja essa página que possa te ajudar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc564906.aspx])

O web service, deverá ser capaz de ler um arquivo XML que contenha todas as informações de uma possível atualização. Optei por utilizar um XML e não um Banco de Dados, pela simplicidade do mesmo.